# How to ge the height of an object inside an image

Tags: java, android, image-processing

I have this picture:

It contains circles inside columns.
 I want to get:

- The height of each circle relative to its column (the distance
  between the column bottom and the circle)
- The height of the whole column
- Classify every column so I can use the data from every column
  differently according to its rank from left to right using java in
  android studio.

I know I'm asking a lot but is that possible?! and if it is how can I do that?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Post the codes which you have tried so far.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the **tour** (https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read the information guides in the **help center** (https://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular, "How to Ask A Good Question" (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), "What Are Good Topics" (https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and "How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example" (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

Yes it must be possible. I have used this concept in Python using OpenCV but not in Java. The idea is to recognise your target inside an image by image recognition and then calculating pixel ratios. Use the same logic and code in Java as OpenCV is there for Java too.

Helper link below,

https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2016/03/28/measuring-size-of-objects-in-an-image-with-opencv/

If you have already started any other implementation and obtaining errors, post it too.

Comment: Did it help you? if so, consider accepting answer. if you have other query, post as seperate question. https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers